# how to remove inlay hints in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, inlay-hints

[image: How can i remove/disable these helper texts in vscode (underlined with red lines)]

How can i remove/disable these helper texts? i am getting these while using react/js/ts and such...

i tried disabling all exttensions and it did not solve the issue so i don't think my problem is extension related

visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing are called "inlay hints".

You can disable them in settings by setting `"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "off"`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! i'll update my question title for others that may have the same problem.